# pass data from PouchDB Service to Controller in AngluarJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, pouchdb

I have set up a PouchDb service in Angular/Ionic which works fine within the service, but fails when I try to pass the data I retrieve from PouchDB service to my controller.

this is my service

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('DBService', function($q) {
  var items;
  var db;
  var self = this;
  this.initDB = function() {
    return db = new PouchDB('simpleDB', {
      adapter: 'websql'
    });
  };
this.storeData = function() {
    return $q.when(
              db.put({
          _id: 'mydoc',
          title: 'some text'
        }).then(function (response) {
          // handle response
          console.log('done')
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err); 
        })
      )
  };
this.getData = function(){
  return $q.when(
    db.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
    // handle doc
    console.log(doc); // I see the data in console
     }).catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
     })
  )
}
})
```

and this is the controller

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, DBService, $q) {
  $scope.getData = function(){
      DBService.initDB()
      DBService.getData().then(function(data){ 
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
```

when I use then() I get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can pass the data correctly from my service to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lucky to find the error quickly! I was not returning the data in my service so I changed it to

```
this.getData = function(){
  return $q.when(
    db.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
    // handle doc
    return doc; // I added this 
    console.log(doc); // I see the data in console
     }).catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
     })
  )
}
```

and the reason for the then() returning undefined was that accidentally I had omitted return $q.when( from the second line of the  this.getData function! Now I have my data in the controller just as I needed!